# Can I add fields to the "New Individual" popup window?

Tags: civicontribute, contacts

When adding a new contribution we have the option of a quick entry popup for "New Individual" when associating it with a contact, which shows up as follows:

[image: New Individual]

Is there a way to add additional fields here? For example, address fields and/or phone number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

This form is actually a configurable profile. To edit it:

1. Go to *Administer > Customize Data & Screens > Profiles*
2. Click on the "Reserved Profiles" tab.
3. Find the "New Individual" profile and click "Fields" to add or modify the list of fields:

[image]